# Play video using GStreamer

Tags: qt, gstreamer, meego

I am trying to build a projet for playing video using Gstreamer on linux embedded system from [How to play video in Qt on MeeGo using GStreamer](http://www.developer.nokia.com/Community/Wiki/How_to_play_video_in_Qt_on_MeeGo_using_GStreamer) 
I have the Gstreamer package on my device(I can run video with gstreamer commands from shell), but when I try to compile the project it failed because of the lines :

```
CONFIG += link_pkgconfig
PKGCONFIG += gstreamer-0.10 gstreamer-interfaces-0.10
in the .pro file
```

The output error:

```
 Project ERROR: Package gstreamer-0.10 not found
 make: *** [Makefile] Error 2
```

Any idea how to use link_pkgconfig correctly?

Answer (score 2):

When you need to link to a library, you need the development packages, those are the ones ending in `-dev`. Try installing `libgstreamer0.10-dev`.

Comment: Is this package is appropriate also for embedded system?

Comment: You don't need to install it on the target machine, only on your development machine.

Answer (score 0):

you can use like this also in the LDFLAG

```
`pkg-config --cflags --libs gstreamer-1.0`
```

Thanks